# java spring: configure properties for sql server with integrated authentication

Tags: java, sql-server, spring

I have a simple application in java spring, but I am not able to configure the connection to the local sql server database, which has authentication integrated with windows.

My properties

```
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=mydatabase
    spring.integratedSecurity=true
    spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=false
    spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
```

My database configuration

[image]

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection
>   to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection
>   refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an
>   instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP
>   connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port
>   are not blocked by a firewall.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add  `integratedSecurity=true` in your `spring.datasource.url`.

something like this in your application.properties will do,

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=mydatabase;integratedSecurity=true`

see these link for more information :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/authentication-in-sql-server

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax

Comment: *(1)* find sqljdbc_auth.dll file from microsoft jdbc driver installation folder, one you installed previously from the jdbc driver link. The path would be something like: <installation directory>\sqljdbc_<version>\<language>\auth\

*(2)* copy sqljdbc_auth.dll file to your JAVA_HOME/bin folder.

*(3)* Restart your sql server.